# 1 Errors about client-side and server-side

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, webpack

Basically, in my formhandler.js I have edited the code to be

```
function handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // check what text was put into the form field
  let formText = document.getElementById('name').value;
  console.log("::: Form Submitted :::");
  fetch('/sentiment', {
    method: "POST",
    credentials: "same-origin",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify({ text: document.getElementById('name').value })
   })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(function(res) {
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = res.message;
  });
```

In the client/index.js , I have

```
const button = document.querySelector('#submitname');
button.addEventListener('click', handleSubmit);
```

And my server-side post request looks like:

```
app.post("/sentiment", (req, res) => {
  console.log('sentiment started');
  textapi.language({
    text: req.body.text,
    mode: tweet,
  }, (error, response) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log('u got errored');
      return;
    }
    res.send(response);
  });
});
```

However, I am getting an error that says:

```
formHandler.js:9 POST http://localhost:8080/sentiment 404 (Not Found)
```

What can I do? My project link is below if you want to check other files. I am using WebPack for build and express as my server.
[GitHub Link](https://github.com/argunmuradov/NLP-App)

Comment: Are you actually running your express server or the Webpack dev server? Looks like you should be running `npm run build-prod && npm start` to build and run the entire app

Comment: @Phil , That is what I am doing.

Comment: Try removing the `app.get('/', ...)` route. You shouldn't need it anyway. Have you tried testing the API with Postman or Curl?